# How do I change index page content in Vuejs/Nuxt2?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm currently calling my `MainPage.vue` from the components folder to appear in my `index.vue` by using the following.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <MainPage/>
  </div>
</template>
```

My question: How can I use a button click in the index page, to change the MainPage to another page. I'm basically running the site's navigation in the index, and I want to have the content change upon clicking a button.

Comment: I recommend that you put your navigation into `/layouts/default.vue` so that it wraps all of your pages, then you can use either a `<nuxt-link>` or `$router.push` to move from page to page. Pages being generated by the files in the `pages` directory of course. Reminder: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing

Comment: After I put it in the default.vue in the layouts folder. Now it overwrites the /pages/index.vue and the nuxt-link works in the url bar, but it won't show the content for the page. It keeps showing the default page content only.

Comment: If your layout is properly done (check documentation), it should wrap all the pages not overwrite them. And the router will move accordingly. You can always provide us a [repro] if it's still not working.

Comment: Ill retry creating the layout in a new project, thanks for the advise. Greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Turns out I was missing the <Nuxt /> Tag in the default.vue, it's all working accordingly now. Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, this is what I assumed regarding your previous comment (that it wasn't working) haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your navigation into `/layouts/default.vue` to wrap all of your pages. Then you will be able to use either `nuxt-link` or `$router.push` to move from page to page.

Here is the documentation on how routes work in Nuxt: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing/

Here is how layouts work: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/views#default-layout

PS: in Nuxt2, pay attention to the needed `<nuxt />` tag for your layout like this

```html
<template>
  <nuxt />
</template>
```